# How to understand "Would you say what you felt was a feeling of betrayal"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I think I am hard to understand

> Would you say what you felt was a feeling of betrayal?

What's the meaning? Is it correct in grammar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct.

First, there is an understood "that" in the sentence which might help it be more clear:

> Would you say [that] what you felt was a feeling of betrayal?

This is a good example of a couple of things in English:

- Entire sub-clauses can take the place of a single word in English, and assume its function in a main clause.  *Would you say X* - X can be a single-word noun, a noun phrase with adjectives and prepositional phrases, or an entire clause with its own subject/verb that functions as a noun.
- Many words can be used to indicate the beginning of a clause in the middle of a sentence - *that* is one of them, but in many cases the *that* can be omitted.
- Words like *what*, *where*, etc. can be used as *indefinite pronouns*.  A pronoun takes the place of a noun - however, an indefinite pronoun takes the place of a noun that is not yet known to the speaker/writer.  We don't know exactly "what"

As far as the overall meaning - asking someone *would you say X* is a way to see if someone agrees that your words express something they are having trouble expressing, or to confirm that you understand what someone is experiencing or reporting.

Answer (score 4):

It's not incorrect, but you could shorten it and retain the same meaning:

> *Would you say you felt a feeling of betrayal?*

Or, shorter still:

> *Did you feel a feeling of betrayal?*

Or, even shorter:

> *Did you feel betrayed?*

You've essentially said the same thing, but in a much more wordy way.